# How to disable ActiveStorage Analyzers and Previewers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activestorage

I have a Rails 5.2.3 app using ActiveStorage. By default, ActiveStorage would run some background jobs to extract metadata from attached files, and/or create thumbnail images for previews.

I don't want that. I don't need any metadata, nor do I need any thumbnails. So how can I disable these background jobs?

According to the [official Rails guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-active-storage), I've set

```
config.active_storage.analyzers = []
config.active_storage.previewers = []
```

in `/config/application.rb`.

However, looks like it doesn't help. When running `rails test`, I still see

```
[ActiveJob] [ActiveStorage::AnalyzeJob] Performing ActiveStorage::AnalyzeJob (Job ID: 741592f5-c5e4-48d7-8cf9-158790fb8a00) from Inline(default) with arguments: #<GlobalID:0x00005642f9050748 @uri=#<URI::GID >>
[ActiveJob] [ActiveStorage::AnalyzeJob] (22.0ms)  SAVEPOINT active_record_1
[ActiveJob] [ActiveStorage::AnalyzeJob] ActiveStorage::Blob Update (22.7ms)  UPDATE `active_storage_blobs` SET `metadata` = '{\"identified\":true,\"analyzed\":true}' WHERE `active_storage_blobs`.`id` = 3056
[ActiveJob] [ActiveStorage::AnalyzeJob] (21.9ms)  RELEASE SAVEPOINT active_record_1
```

I've also tried via an initializer file:

```
# /config/initializers/active_storage_disable_analyze.rb
Rails.application.config.active_storage.analyzers.delete ActiveStorage::Analyzer::ImageAnalyzer
Rails.application.config.active_storage.analyzers.delete ActiveStorage::Analyzer::VideoAnalyzer
```

But this doesn't help neither.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no easy way to disable Analyzers completely. Rails falls back to [NullAnalyzer](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activestorage/lib/active_storage/analyzer/null_analyzer.rb) when you delete the Image/Video analyzers, which doesn't gather any metadata.

You can see where it defaults [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/ee10e05af27facf42b1c49f8aaa0463d3af6989c/activestorage/app/models/active_storage/blob/analyzable.rb#L55)

Answer (score 5):

I did not want or need any analysis at all, ever, and over-riding the module methods seemed to do the trick.

```
ActiveStorage::Blob::Analyzable.module_eval do

  def analyze_later
  end

  def analyzed?
    true
  end
end
```

Quite early days so I cannot guarantee no side effects but so far so good, no longer seeing any ActiveStorage::AnalyzeJob entries in my sidekiq log and the blobs seem perfectly usable, download links work etc.

Comment: What do you name this file and where do you save it?

Comment: `app/decorators/active_storage/blob/analyzable_decorator.rb`


You may also need to add `require 'active_storage/blob/analyzable'`

Comment: @aqwan, I don't understand the `/decorators/` file structure. Are you requiring 'decorators' somewhere?

Comment: I know it's probably terrible, I but added this code to the end of the model file that `has_one_attached`. I tried adding it to an initializer, application.rb, my environment files. All other locations broke method calls elsewhere in `ActiveStorage::Blob`

Comment: @Chiperific - yes, seems like in 5.2 I have had to add following to application.rb 




`# Load decorators as late as possible so models being extended already autoloaded
    %w[ decorators ].each do |dir|
      config.to_prepare do
        Dir.glob(File.join(Rails.root, 'app', dir, '**/*_decorator.rb')).each { |c| require_dependency(c) }
      end
    end`

Comment: @aqwan Thank you very much for this. It helped me to locate a problem in our test suite.

Comment: This is not a bad solution, but overriding `analyze_later` is unnecessary since returning `true` from `analyzed?` will always effectively skip the job. The ability to manually trigger it could come in handy. Also putting it in the model file as @Chiperific mentions doesn't limit its effect to that model. It might be an error-free place, but will still override these methods globally.

Answer (score 2):

config/initializers/override_as_blob.rb

```
Rails.application.config.to_prepare do
  ActiveStorage::Blob.class_eval do
    def analyzed?
    # Do whatever override
      if checksum.blank?
        true
      else
        super
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

I prefer a clear way by removing the auto call.

```
Rails.application.config.to_prepare do
  ActiveStorage::Attachment.skip_callback(:commit, :after, :analyze_blob_later)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the Analyzers globally, which will only end up running the `NullAnalyzer`:

```rb
ActiveStorage.analyzers = []
```

For something more selective, you can wrap them in a subclass that overrides their `.accept?(blob)`.

For instance we use a custom ActiveStorage service class to encrypt some uploads, but it doesn't support the streaming download used by `ActiveStorage::AnalyzeJob`. We disabled the analyze only for attachments using that service this way:

```rb
ActiveStorage.analyzers.map! do |klass|
  Class.new(klass) do
    def self.accept?(blob)
      return false if blob.service.is_a?(EncryptedS3Service)
      super
    end
  end
end
```